# If the probability of winning is now 75%, what happened?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

In a certain game, players can do good (G), bad (B), or average (M). Players play one at a time, not at the same time. In way to win, a player needs to do better than the opponent. So G> B and M, M>B. If they do the same, then they need to repeat all the game.

Let's say that Player A does G or B with probability of $50\%$ while player B does G, B, or M with probability $\frac{1}{3}$.

You can't see the game but you know that one of the players between players A and B has finished playing and the table of winning probabilities says that Player A has now $75\%$ chance of winning. What has happened in the game?

---

$P(A wins) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{3} + \frac{2}{6}P(A wins) = \frac{1}{2} = 0.5 $

$0.5(1+X) = 0.75 \rightarrow \frac{0.75}{0.50} - 1 = 0.5 $

So the probability of A has increased by 0.5. It means that A has done G. What do you think?

Comment: Sure, $\frac{0.75}{0.50} - 1 = 0.5$ is a true equation. It is true as long as we are doing real arithmetic; we don't need to know anything about the game to agree with this equation. What does that equation tell us about anything in the question? To put it another way: I'm sure you had some particular idea in mind about how this equation is supposed to solve things for us, but you did not tell us. Try using a few more words, and maybe not use symbols like $\rightarrow$ when you don't absolutely need to.

Comment: You have 5 possibilities for what has happened. You must calculate the probabity that A will win for each of them and see in which case you get 0.75.

Comment: What is $X$? Why do you think it is relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will show that $A$ has done $G$ is *not the correct answer*. I will leave it for you to follow the same approach to get to the right answer.

At the beginning of a new game, the probability of $A$ winning is $0.5$ as you obtained. If $A's$ probability of win has *increased* to $0.75$, what are likely cases? It must be that either $A$ had the first turn and finished well or $B$ had the first turn and finished poorly.

Case $1$: player $A$ played first and did good ($G$).

$ \displaystyle P(A ~ \text{wins}) = \frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{5}{6} \gt 0.75$

Explanation: $A$ has already finished with a $G$. Now there is $2/3$ chance that $B$ finishes with $B$ or $M$ ensuring a win for $A$ or there is a tie with probability $1/3$ in which case a new game starts afresh and from the beginning of a game probability of a win for $A$ is $1/2$.

Now what happens in case where player $B$ played first and did badly ($B$)? Can you find the probability of $A's$ win?